# ERROR invalid conversion from 'int' to 'wezelbst' (-fpermissive) C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the following code:

```
void dodaj(BST * T)
{
    T->iloscwezlow();

    int i,n;

    wezelbst * x;

    cin >> n;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x=static_cast<int>(rand()%10);
        T->wstaw(x);      
    }

    cout << endl;
    T->walk(T->korzen);
    T->iloscwezlow();      
}
```

Here's my problem :

```
In function 'void dodaj(BST*)':
[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'wezelbst*' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should post code in english.

Comment: @StephaneRolland the faulty line is English. You should instead ask how 'wezelbst' is defined.

Comment: @Njol sure the faulty line is x=static_cast<int>(rand()%10);. However the code posted on SO should be in english.

Comment: @StephaneRolland, if one wants to increase the chances of getting help then yes, the code should be in English. However it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You write:

```
x=static_cast<int>(rand()%10);
```

there you try to assign to x a integer value.

However you have defined x as a pointer:

```
wezelbst * x;
```

What do you expect to happen ? pointers to wezelbst and integer are not related, the compiler cannot know what you want to do.

A little advice also (good practice), you should initialize your variables when you declare them.

```
int i = 0;
int n = 0;
wezelbst * x = nullptr;
```